# Xcode 4 Documentation filter

Tags: xcode4

In previous versions of Xcode we had the ability to filter which document sets to search from. I cannot find this feature in Xcode 4. Is it simply absent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the magnifying glass icon in the search bar, and click "Show Find Options".

Alternatively, use the great [Ingredients](http://fileability.net/ingredients/) doc viewer.